# Lubricating distillation glassware with coconut oil or olive?

Tags: organic-chemistry

For the joints
Is there parts that don't need to be lubricated ?
How often should I lubricate if I plan on distilling water for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often joints are greased only if either a) you distill under vacuum, b) you heat above say 130 or $\pu{150 °C}$, c) you distill something agressive (against glass), like strongly basic or acidic material, or something that over time may polymerise, d) you need to pertain flexibility of the joints during the distillation, like rotating around an axis -- for example you collect several fractions.  If so, you need something that is not liquid at the temperature range of application; otherwise, it potentially may drop into the inner of the distillation.  Hence there are several greases foreseen for such an application.

Otherwise (taking into account your profile name, too), especially if you aim to isolate otherwise volatile materials by steam distillation, you may seal the joints with sleaves of PFTE / Teflon.  Nothing will drop into your distillation; but after the concluded distillation, start to dissamble carefully the *still warm* glass ware.

[image]

([picture source](http://www.scilabware.com/Adapters/PTFE-Sleeves/p-1-334/))